# Set a layout over another layout

Tags: android, css, android-layout, layout

I've got a menu layout which consists of 2 borders where I set some icons:

[MenuView http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/4314/hjcg.png](http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/4314/hjcg.png)

And another layout which consists on a custom title bar.

My objective is to create a layout using this booth layouts:

[ComposeView http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/2121/d6zp.png](http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/2121/d6zp.png)

This is the XML file:

**MenuView.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:orientation="horizontal" >


<include layout="@layout/custom_tittlebar" >
</include>


<RelativeLayout   
    android:id="@+id/border_left"
    android:layout_width="80dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:
    android:background="@drawable/border_cut" >
    
    <ImageView
        ... />
    
    <ImageView
        ... />
    
    <ImageView
        ... />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/border_right"
    android:layout_width="80dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@drawable/border_cut" >
    
    <ImageView
        ... />
    
    <ImageView
        ... />
    
    <ImageView
        .. />
        
    <ImageView
        ... />
   
</RelativeLayout>
```

**custom_titlebar.xm**

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/title"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="35dip"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#000000" >

<com.example.medialauncher.DigitalClock 
    android:id="@+id/digitalClock" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:text="DigitalClock" 
    android:textSize="10pt" 
    android:textColor="#00C2FF"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

The problem is that instead of getting what I explained with the image abobe, what I'm getting is this:

[Fail http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/7541/qore.png](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/7541/qore.png)

This is, what I need is the custom_titlebar to be on top of the other layouts.

Comment: try to include `custom_titlebar.xml` at the end of parent `layout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <RelativeLayout     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <RelativeLayout   
    android:id="@+id/border_left"
    android:layout_width="80dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="@drawable/border_cut" >

    .....
  </RelativeLayout>

  <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/border_right"
     android:layout_width="80dip"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_gravity="right"
     android:background="@drawable/border_cut" >

.....
 </RelativeLayout>


 <include layout="@layout/custom_tittlebar" >
 </include>
 </RelativeLayout>
```